# System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe methods incompatible with F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, unsafe

The [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) package defines several methods which the F# compiler shows as having input or output type `nativeptr<unit>`.  These methods include `AsPointer`, `AsRef`, `Copy`, `CopyBlock`, `InitBlock`, `Read`, and `Write`, plus a few others.

However, any attempt to use these methods generates the following compile error:

`error FS0001: A generic construct requires that the type 'nativeptr<unit>' have reference semantics, but it does not, i.e. it is a struct`

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il) for the package, it that `nativeptr<unit>` corresponds to `void*` in the corresponding IL methods.

Is there any workaround for this?  Alternatively, how could the IL methods be modified to work with F#?